# Can I replace the permanent filter in my furnace?

Tags: furnace, filter

In my furnace (ruud ubhc-17j14sfa), there is a permanent, washable filter.  It was there when we moved in 2 years ago.  The house is about 10 years old now.  The filter is pretty simple, more like a strong mesh.  I don't just want to replace the filter as the it might effect the airflow going to the furnace and cause issues, or have the furnace work harder.

Does anyone have experience with this?  would it be ok to replace it with a higher MERV rating without causing any issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just order a new filter if that makes you feel better.  There is nothing wrong with replacing it.  However most of the permanent ones can be washed in the dishwasher.  I would look at the manufacturers guide and just clean it - as if something isn't broke why fix it.  I have found getting replacements can be off by a little and cause issues.  But you could always keep old one until you are sure what you ordered works.  I would not leave the furnace without a filter.

Comment: Thanks, Its more about how effective it is at capturing air particles, which is doesn't look like it is.  I've cleaned it several times already.  I'm worried that replacing it with a higher MERV rating will reduce airflow to the furnace.

Comment: @David - That is always the discussion point.  Will a better filter decrease air flow and make furnace work hard (or quit working).  I would call RUUD and ask them as this is 10 years old and they may have alternatives now.  Also you could look at an electric filter.  I don't think there is anyone on here that can accurately tell you what to do with your RUUD furnace other than only using manufacturer endorsed filters.

Comment: If it is the electrostatic type they cost ~100. USD they dont look like they take a lot out but if cleaned every 30 days they work for years. Every now and then they need a soap to really clean them especially if there is a smoker in the house or a lot of smoke from the kitchen.